# RPN (Postfix) Calculator. Not Accepting Input The Way I Want

Tags: python, python-2.7

i, I've written a RPN calculator but it's not printing or taking input the way I'm after.

At the moment it takes input and prints like this:

```
5 5 +
10
```

Where as I want to input it this way

```
5
5
+
=
10
```

This is my code so far:

```
def op_pow(stack):
    b = stack.pop(); a = stack.pop()
    stack.append(a ** B)/>/>
def op_mul(stack):
    b = stack.pop(); a = stack.pop()
    stack.append(a * B)/>/>
def op_div(stack):
    b = stack.pop(); a = stack.pop()
    stack.append(a / B)/>/>
def op_add(stack):
    b = stack.pop(); a = stack.pop()
    stack.append(a + B)/>/>
def op_sub(stack):
    b = stack.pop(); a = stack.pop()
    stack.append(a - B)/>/>
def op_num(stack, num):
    stack.append(num)

ops = {
 '^': op_pow,
 '*': op_mul,
 '/': op_div,
 '+': op_add,
 '-': op_sub,
 }

def get_input(inp):

    tokens = inp.strip().split()
    return tokens


def rpn_calc(tokens):
    stack = []
    table = []
    for token in tokens:
        if token in ops:
            ops[token](stack)
            table.append( (token, ' '.join(str(s) for s in stack)) )
        else:
            op_num(stack, eval(token))
            table.append( (token, ' '.join(str(s) for s in stack)) )
    return stack[-1]

while True:

    rp = rpn_calc(get_input((raw_input())))
    print rp
```

I've tried to fix it by changing:

```
rp = rpn_calc(get_input((raw_input())))
print rp
```

to:

```
rp = [get_input(raw_input())]
```

But that doesn't work that doesn't sum as I haven't passed it through the rpn_calc function because when I do I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\rpn.py", line 58, in <module>
    help = rpn_calc[get_input(raw_input())]
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: What is the *full* traceback of the exception?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters When I run it with `rp = rpn_calc[get_input(raw_input()))]` the whole error is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\rpn.py", line 58, in <module>
    help = rpn_calc[get_input(raw_input())]
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: That traceback does not match the code you posted; look carefully at the square brackets..

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `rpn_calc()` function as if indexing into a sequence, using square brackets:

```
rpn_calc[get_input(raw_input())]
```

Make that a proper function call:

```
rpn_calc(get_input(raw_input()))
```

You will have to retool your program, however, to replace the loop over `tokens` to an infinite loop, asking for input each loop iteration and treating that input as a token instead:

```
while True:
    token = raw_input()
```

You probably want to look for an `exit` or `end` token to break out of the loop and program.

Comment: If i type the number 5, then press enter it just prints the number 5. I want it to let me enter the next number, the me press enter, then enter the operand, then press enter and type the equals sign then get it to sum them.

Comment: @JaAnTr: You need to treat each input line separately, acting on the stack after each input line has been received. That means you need to make the input loop central to your `rpn_calc()` function, require quite some rewriting.

Comment: Oh that's not good at all! Thanks for the help. Can you give me any pointers on where to begin, I'm really struggling.

Comment: @JaAnTr: Your program now takes input, takes *all* tokens from that in one go, *then* runs your calculation program. Instead of looping over tokens, loop in in infinite loop and take a token from `raw_input()` each loop iteration.